# Translating song lyrics: 「もういっそこんな人生なんて」って僕は / 世界を壊している

Tags: grammar, meaning, song-lyrics

These sentences are taken from a song lyric [世界を壊している](https://www5.atwiki.jp/hmiku/pages/32471.html) sung by Kagamine Rin and written by Neru. [The song's translation](http://vocaloidlyrics.wikia.com/wiki/%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E3%82%92%E5%A3%8A%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B_(Sekai_o_Kowashite_Iru)) seems off or weird in English.

> 何者にもなれない事が許せなくて
>   冴えない未来というハンマーを　千鳥足で振るっている
>   胸のサイレンさえ打ち砕いて
>   **「もういっそこんな人生なんて」って僕は
>
>   世界を壊している**
>
> ---
>
> 何者にもなれない事くらい知っていたさ
>   結局は単純明快で　僕が全部悪いんでした
>   ならばもう一生独りだって
>   「不器用な愛を振り撒いてやる」って僕は
>   **「もういっそこんな人生だから」って僕は
>
>   世界を壊している**

もう means already:now, いっそ means rather:preferably, and なんて means such as. The line is "もういっそこんな人生なんて" and "もういっそこんな人生だから". Both continues with 世界を壊している。even by knowing the individual words, I still could not interpret the sentences. The translated one says : "I can't live like this!!" And "since this is the life I have to live..." They are not wrong but it feels like the translator is a Japanese learning English. This site definitely does not allow translation, but I want to know how the real meaning is reached by each of the following words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I feel the translator is a native English speaker learning Japanese :) The translation seems satisfactory, at least semantically.

Obviously the song is about someone who is in a desperate state because he failed to be successful in life. He was too late (old) to try something again, and he also realizes he is not very talented. (BTW 「才能は凡人以下だ」 means "*My* talent is below average". It's one of the few mistakes the translator made)

So 世界を壊している here is not about actually destroying the real whole world (of course he is well aware that he is not that powerful). The phrase is euphemistically referring to self-abandonment, or "destroying his *life* itself". He is feeling his life (or "his personal world around him") is really hopeless and meaningless.

- いっそ here is the same as [いっその事](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8). It adds the nuance of "I might as well (destroy)" or "It'd be better to (destroy)" to the sentence. もう is an intensifier.
- ～なんて is used to abuse or make light of something. こんな人生なんて is something like "Damn my life".
- って is a colloquial quotative particle similar to と. (Hence "saying, ...")
- ～だから is of course "because". The last part roughly means "Because my life is like this, I'll even destroy it".